# Regarding mounting S3 bucket in Amazon linux permanently

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mount, s3fs

I have bucket named test bucket and I need to mount this bucket under /var/www/html/upload. the bucket is having 33 GB data. I am using below command  to mount

```
/usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other test         var/www/html/upload
                             [buck name]  [mount point ]
```

it mounted but when I try to list the files it throws error  like as given below

```
  df: ‘/var/www/html/upload: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

1. Also is there any way to change the ownership of the directory in which I have mounted S3 bucket. when I try to do that I getting below error

   cp: preserving permissions for ‘/upload/pp-11415-AfQqcI3t_o.jpg’: Operation not supported

It would be great if someone help on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: would you like to give a try to RIOFS ? Its faster than S3FS. I wrote this blog 3 years back. https://medium.com/@saranjeetsingh/mount-s3-bucket-in-linux-using-riofs-alternative-to-s3fs-53186e12e1cb

Comment: try /usr/bin/s3fs test /var/www/html/upload fuse allow_other,use_cache=/tmp/cache,uid=userid,gid=groupid 0

Comment: cp: preserving permissions for ‘./upload/pp-3892-tV2vDxfE_m.jpg’: Operation not supported

Comment: do you have any idea on above error

Comment: Mostly this error occurs when you are trying to copy files which owned by other user.  have to you tried with sudo ?

Comment: relevant for that error: https://askubuntu.com/questions/193898/preserve-permission-switch-not-working-with-cp

Comment: yes I am trying with root user only still getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my steps:

- Lauch Amazon Linux AMI : amzn-ami-hvm-2018.03.0.20200602.1-x86_64-gp2 (ami-05ca073a83ad2f28c)
- Install S3FS from https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Installation-Notes
- Install aws cli : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html
- Create test bucket :  test-bucket
- Create IAM role with below policy

  ```
  {
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
     {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":[
           "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
     },
     {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":[
           "s3:ListBucket",
           "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket"
     },
     {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":[
           "s3:PutObject",
           "s3:PutObjectAcl",
           "s3:GetObject",
           "s3:GetObjectAcl",
           "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
     }
  ]
  ```

  }
- Attach Role to instance. Role is test-role
- created /upload directory
- finally use below command to mount s3 bucket.

  > sudo s3fs -o iam_role="test-role " -o
  > url="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" -o endpoint=eu-cal-1 -o
  > dbglevel=info -o curldbg -o allow_other -o use_cache=/tmp test-bucket
  > /upload
- verify mount folder

  df -h
- change ownership

  sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /upload
- Able to create test file in /upload with some content and also can see same file in S3 console.

Hope it will help you.